# How can aliens take over the [Medieval] world without force?

Tags: technology, aliens, medieval

The Kroll Technocracy is a xenophilic and pacifist conglomerate consisting of 3 different alien mammalian species,They have a high sense of morality and would like to annex earth without bloodshed,How can they achieve their goal and integrate humanity in their stellar federation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take the Roman approach.

Until Caesar, the expansion of the Roman territories was largely due to their advanced technology.  They would go into "barbarian" lands and build forts which would grow into cities.  The roman outposts would have things that the locals had never seen before, including concrete and construction techniques that amazed them.  The Romans would then make deals with local Chieftans to send their sons to Rome to be educated.  When in Rome, the sons of the chieftans would live in luxury and raised the Roman way, and eventually go back to rule their people with Roman values instilled in them.

Imagine an Alien race doing something similar, but on a grander scale.  "You won't have to worry about food, illness, or even have to work as hard as you have.  Help us build our cities, and we will give all these gifts to you."  Again, send the children to the alien world or a faraway outpost on this one to be educated.  Let them grow up thinking that the Aliens are very benevolent, and allow the areas to self govern, with only a small tribute given to the alien home world.  After a generation or two, they will have installed local leaders very loyal to them.  If there was any rebellion or disobedience, send the local loyal areas to crush rebellious ones, but never send your own troops.  Increase the amount of gifts to loyal areas, and take them away from any that showed disloyalty,

Comment: Isn't that identical to the "Hitler approach"?  "I'll solve your economic problem if you give me full control"-Also Hitler came to power faster than in "a generation or two".

Comment: Still going to get a bunch of fearful panic-stricken mobs who are afraid of the aliens. (Upvote anyway!)

Comment: @Nate Dukes: The difference presumably being that the aliens actually can offer all those things :-)  Personally, I've always found a lot of those "Earthlings fight the high-tech but basically decent aliens because we're all humans"-type stories pretty hard to swallow.

Comment: @NateDukes Mine is actually based on historical fact instead of fiction.

Comment: Are you saying that Hitler's rise to power was fictional?

Comment: @NateDukes No, just that people have a very inaccurate idea of HOW hitler rose to power.

Answer (score 2):

### Religion.

With their advanced technology (or even just with technology we real humans have currently) your aliens could rather easily convince the entirety of the human population to believe they were gods/angels/supernatural agents.

They could then convince humans to do anything they liked, including but not limited to:

- Not killing each other.
- Develop science and rationality.
- Learn to love, respect and tolerate each other no matter how different.

After they have learned to do former (aided by yet more advanced technology), the aliens can then explain (or hopefully have humanity understand this on their own) that they are not gods, but people from different worlds.

There is no doubt that the human population will be infinitely greatful (and tolerant) towards the aliens since they did afterall enlighten them. Earth can then be seamlessly annexed. No need for any massive cultural/societal exchange, the people of earth have already been intergrating Kroll values since decades/centuries.

Comment: Wellllllll, they're going to have a hard time convincing atheists and anyone who remembers the Arthur C. Clarke quote. You know, the one about advanced technologies seeming like magic.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Arthur C. Clarke was not a medieval writer. And atheism was essentially nonexistant during the medieval time period. Believe me, people during the middle-ages were very much gullible.

Comment: I forgot about the time period! Then I think you're right.

Comment: No offense intended, _but_ I feel this is overly optimistic. The first two are perfectly plausible, but the second? One has to _choose_ to love, respect, and tolerate differences, and that means being open to the very _idea_ first. In our day we struggle with this, how can aliens succeed? Never mind the fact that after they reveal they _aren't_ gods, someone will likely become suspicious of the aliens and maybe even foment a rebellion.

Answer (score 1):

Do it Hitler style.  He did something that would generally be impossible under normal circumstances- In your world/book you could create some sort of conflict that requires immediate attention.

Hitler became a dictator not by means of military, but by means of his people, Hitler became a dictator because his people wanted to give him the power.  The great depression was an immense problem for the people of the 1900s, and Hitler told them that he could solve all of their problems.  He was smart, not stupid, the aliens should be able to take his example and conquer the medieval lands.  Rule with an iron fist cloaked in a velvet glove, or something like that- Ceasar.

You'll want to make the aliens seem like they have good intentions, and they very well may have good intentions, you never disclosed that information.  People in the middle ages weren't exactly as 'informed' as we are today, and they would likely be willing to believe pretty much anything.

Comment: Hitler was not elected, he was appointed by Hindenburg.  Also, the Nazis did not take over by election, they never got more than a plurality, even after they outlawed other parties.

Comment: Guess my history teacher from 9th grade was an idiot then, apologies.  Hold up, Hitler did rise to power because the people wanted him to come to power; Hindenberg only made him Chancellor, the rest was Hitler's cunning.  He became Dictator because of "The Act," and people had to vote for that to pass.

Comment: Yes, your history teacher owes you an apology. The Nazis never had more than 10% membership the people did not to WANT to give him power, it was seized through threats and intimidation.  They never got  more than 34% of the vote prior to seizing power, and never got a majority even after they banned all other parties., hardly the Svengali like powers you are ascribing to them.

Answer (score 1):

Details are important here. To take over the Earth "without force", and "without bloodshed" are two very different questions!

The aliens are in a technologically superior position, so they are the more powerful side here. The Roman approach, as explained by AngelPray, does indeed rely on force (the known strength of the Roman empire) though it is not obvious.

A war continues until one side can no longer keep up. Thus, the those where the sides have very similar force are the bloodiest. For instance, an improvement of helmets does not necessarily save lives if invented by the weaker side. It only makes the war last longer. To prevent such a long-war situation, either do not use force, **or as much force that you possibly can**.